# Bash to Calculate PPS

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I had made a small bash script by which pps from a interface can be calculated. Once the incoming pps reach a desired limit then it executes a command.

I am getting an error while running the script can someone please help me

This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

INTERVAL="1"  # update interval in seconds
LIMIT="3000" # Limit in KB/S
URL1="http://1.1.1.1/abcd.php"
IFS=( ens3 ) # Interface names

while true
do
        for i in "${IFS[@]}"
        do
            R1=$(cat /sys/class/net/$i/statistics/rx_packets)
            T1=$(cat /sys/class/net/$i/statistics/tx_packets)
            sleep $INTERVAL
            R2=$(cat /sys/class/net/$i/statistics/rx_packets)
            T2=$(cat /sys/class/net/$i/statistics/tx_packets)
            TBPS=$(expr $T2 - $T1)
            RBPS=$(expr $R2 - $R1)

            echo "Incoming $i: $RKBPS pps || Outgoing $i: $TKBPS pps"
            if (( $RKBPS > $LIMIT )); then
                # Incoming Limit Exceeded
                #bash $URL1
                #sleep 10
                curl $URL1
                sleep 320
            fi
        done
done
```

Error I am getting as below

```
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
Incoming ens3:  pps || Outgoing ens3:  pps
./s.sh: line 22: ((: > 3000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 3000 ")
```

can someone please help me. T.I.A

Comment: When you copy from here: https://www.xmodulo.com/measure-packets-per-second-throughput-high-speed-network-interface.html read the entire document and copy all!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up two variables `TBPS` and `RBPS` but then refer to `TKBPS` and `RKBPS` instead.

You should also add a brief `sleep` outside the `if` statement otherwise it will consume a lot of CPU as it will be in a tight loop when the value is not exceeded.

Comment: On closer inspection it seems you do have a `sleep`, I must've glanced over it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

The `if` instead of this:

```
 if (( $RKBPS > $LIMIT )); then
```

should be:

```
 if [ "$RKBPS" -gt "$LIMIT" ]; then
```

And this is quite odd method to shape the traffic. Maybe you can implement some traffic shaper as software.

Also the variables you get from `rx_packets` is about packets per seconds, not bytes per second. You should use `rx_bytes`

You forget also to add this before `if` (to convert bytes in kilobytes):

```
TKBPS=$(expr $TBPS / 1024)
RKBPS=$(expr $RBPS / 1024)
```

Comment: The `if (( $RKBPS > $LIMIT )); then` is valid. The problem is the undefined variables

Comment: @roaima, these `))` looks odd for me in `if`. But there are other issues too.

Comment: `if (( RKBPS > LIMIT )); then` would also be fine and that undefined `RKBPS` would then be taken as 0 instead of causing the error. That's all from ksh in the mid 80s. `expr` you would have used in the late 70s or early 80s maybe or when you had to use the Bourne shell or one of its pre-POSIX clones for a reason or another before the mid 90s.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I just copy the lines from the web page I mention in comment. Seems like OP copy the mix the parts of code. About `((` as I said - just feel for me uncomfortable :D